# MyBatis .. trim, where caluse not working as expected

Tags: mybatis

I am working on a application where I am using mybatis and spring.
The application has a search part and I have added few search criteria, according to requirement.
The grid fetched the data without any criteria and its working fine but when I am adding something to criteria it is still showing the same data.
The values are passing to the  function are printed on the logs file as expected.
The problem is at the end when I called the method of DAO where a dynamic sql need to be create and executes but it is not working as expected. 
Below is the code which I am refering:

```
<select id="getAllMemberDetails" resultMap="result_members" parameterType="member">  
    SELECT ID, FNAME, LNAME, ADDRESS, ACTIVE, AMOUNT, EMAIL, JOINDATE
    FROM MEMBERS WHERE 1=1 
    <trim prefix="WHERE" prefixOverrides="AND | OR">
        <if test="fname != null">FNAME = #{fname}</if>
        <if test="lname != null">AND LNAME = #{lname}</if>
        <if test="address != null">AND ADDRESS = #{address}</if>
        <if test="active != null">AND ACTIVE = #{active}</if>
        <if test="joinDate != null">AND JOINDATE &lt;= #{joinDate}</if>
        <if test="amount!= -1">AND AMOUNT= #{amount}</if>
    </trim> 
</select>
```

Here is the java code:

> public List getAllMemberDetails(RowBounds rowBounds, Member
>   mbr);

Here I am using ***trim tag***, I also tried where tag and other related options but its not working.
If anyone knows anything, please let me know.

Thanks
Atul

Comment: Please explain `but it is not working as expected.`....................

Comment: Hi Karthik,It was my mistake, one of the property was not set properly and becuase of that the trim caluse is appended but the criteria for quesry was set a worng value. So the quesry reurn the negative result.